# Sorting data by class for each date

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, match, grouping

I have some datasets which I need to be able to group by `uniquenameclass` for each date. In my example data below I have used `UniqueNameClass1`, `UniqueNameClass3` etc, however in reality they will be text strings only. So what I need to be able to do is cycle through the csv selecting a group which is all the same date then, then group within this date group by the `UniqueNameClass`. If this is difficult to understand hopefully this example will shed some light on the problem I have:

#### raw data

```
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text 
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
```

#### data sorted by date and then grouped by UniqueNameClass

```
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass4,text,text
text,text,text,13/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text
```

So only data of the same date can be grouped together by `UniqueNameClass`. I know in this example I have put the groups chronologically in reality it doesn't matter on the order of the groups, just that each row from each groups on a given date are next to each other.

### Edit

I have attempted to run the code supplied by phihag, quite a few different ways however everything I have tried has yielded the traceback:

```
File "C:\RawDataeDataTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = list(csv.reader(io.StringIO('RawDataeDataTest.csv')))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

The code that I thought would work in accordance with both the code supplied and the comments provided were:

```
import csv
import io

data = list(csv.reader(io.StringIO('RawDataeDataTest.csv')))
data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
print(u'\n'.join(u','.join(row) for row in data))
```

and

```
import csv
import io

data = list(csv.reader('RawDataeDataTest.csv'))
data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
print(u'\n'.join(u','.join(row) for row in data))
```

For the latter I actually get a different traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\RawDataeDataTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
  File "C:\RawDataeDataTest.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Two negative votes already, what do i need to do to rectify this? Not enough detail ?

Comment: No, the level of detail is fine, but you [haven't shown interest in solving this problem yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: There are plenty of questions about replacing existing CSV files with new data; the answer is always: write to a temporary file, then move that file back to the original name when done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply provide a [`key` function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions) to [`sort`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) that extracts the right fields, like this:

```
import csv
import io

s = u'''text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,11/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,10/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass3,text,text
text,text,text,12/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass1,text,text
text,text,text,10/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass2,text,text
text,text,text,10/03/12,text,text,text,UniqueNameClass5,text,text'''

data = list(csv.reader(io.StringIO(s)))
data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
print(u'\n'.join(u','.join(row) for row in data))
```

To read from a file instead of a constant string, simply pass in the [opened](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) file:

```
with open('RawDataeDataTest.csv', 'rb') as csvf:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvf))
data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))
print(u'\n'.join(u','.join(row) for row in data))
```

If you want to store the result in the same file again, write it to a temporary file first, and then move it atomically:

```
import csv
import functools
import io
import tempfile
import os
import sys

filename = 'RawDataeDataTest.csv'

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    open_args = lambda mode: {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'mode': mode}
else:
    open_args = lambda mode: {'mode': mode + 'b'}

with io.open(filename, **open_args('r')) as csvf:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvf))
data.sort(key=lambda row: (row[3], row[7]))


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(filename), delete=False,
                                 **open_args('w')) as of:
    try:
        csv.writer(of).writerows(data)
        of.flush()
    except:
        os.unlink(of.name)
        raise

    try:
        os.replace(of.name, filename)
    except AttributeError:  # Python < 3.3
        if os.name == 'nt':
            os.remove(filename)
        os.rename(of.name, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am exploring this now.I am pretty new to coding a lot of what I have learn has been done so by reverse engineering others code. However sometimes, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Well I have been trying this code out now for the best part of two hours, with reading documentation of various functions to find out what the issue is. The traceback I keep recieving is :  ` line 10, in <module>`
   ` data = list(csv.reader(io.StringIO(rawdata)))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not file`

Comment: Are you trying it on your data or like it was posted here?

Comment: Yes indeed although read from a csv file. I am not sure if I am using the correct methods of inporting the csv.

Comment: @GTPE If you're reading from a file, you should name the file variable something other than `rawdata` (for example `rawfile`), and then read with `dat = list(csv.reader(rawfile))`.

Comment: @phihag I have added detail about my attempts. It could well be that I am doing something extremely stupid in the way I am attempting to open the file.

Comment: @GTPE Added code that uses a file. As usual, when you want to open a file, you'll need to call the [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: @phihag Sorry for the slow reply, I had some more pressing work to do. Coming back to this I cannot get your code to work on a csv containing the exact data above. It prints the contents of the csv, but doesn't sort it at all. Column 7 is still not in any sort of order. Any ideas what I am doing wrong if at all ?

Comment: Can you upload the *exact* code and data you're using somewhere? I get [this output](https://gist.github.com/phihag/7039021#file-output-csv), which looks fine to me.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, the code works perfectly. I spent too long away from this project I forgot what it was supposed to do!

Comment: @AEA Added code to write the csv to the same file. It's a little bit complicated in order to support both Python 2 and 3, and avoid losing the information even if an error occurs.